# Yubikey public key recovery

Tags: yubikey

I previously created and installed a private key and certificate on a **Yubikey** dongle, my harddrive died so effectively have a new machine.

Is there any way I can obtain and reinstall my gpg PUBLIC key from the Yubikey so I can continue signing my code commits without needing to redo the entire key creation process?

I don't want or have the private key, just want to install the public key so I can continue using it.

Comment: There probably is, but what happened to your backups?

Comment: I didn't expect I'd need them.  The public key could be shared safely anywhere so would like to believe the Yubikey also held this and could read this public key easily from the device.


As it happens I found the solution was recovering the public key from someone I'd shared it with and use this command


```gpg2 --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key {my pub key}```

(I didn't want to backup the private key since it defeats the purpose of the hardware)